# C# ArrayList - object

Tags: c#

I have three classes in my C# program.
Get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'Register_Employee.Employee'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)  C:\Users\x64\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Register Employee\Register
>   Employee\EmployeeList.cs  20  20  Register Employee

I know what the problem is. You have to return the correct type of object, but I don't know how to solve it.
I have a class Employee, a class EmployeeList which holds employees and the main program.

```
namespace Register_Employee
{
    class EmployeeList
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

       public void addEmployee(Employee a)
       {
           this.list.Add(a);
       }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int Index)
        {
            var e = list[Index]; <<<<<The problems
            return e;  <<<<<The problems
        }

    }
}

namespace Register_Employee
{
    class Employee
    {

        public Employee(String iD, String firstName, String lastName)
        {
            this.ID = iD;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
        }

        public String ID { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` when `List<Employee>` would be more descriptive and type safe?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using non-generic collections?

Comment: Hi!
I very new to programming and I don't know what you mean by that, non-generic collections that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to explicitly cast:

```
Employee e = (Employee)list[Index];
```

Also, you could use a `List<Employee>` instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to type cast `object` to `Employee` object

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Index)
{
    var e = list[Index]; 
    return (Employee)e;  
}
```

.Net framework 2.0 or later has a generic class `List` which you can use instead of `ArrayList`. Represents a **strongly typed** list of objects that can be accessed by index. Check on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

In that case

```
class EmployeeList
{
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: "if your ... 2.0 or later" : notice the `var`.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem in a couple of ways.

First if a thing is stored as an object but is actually a derived type you can always cast it to the appropriate type.

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Index)
    {
        var e = list[Index]; 
        return (Employee)e; 
    }
```

However you loose type safety in doing so.  A better solution is to use generics

```
class EmployeeList
{
   List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();

   public void addEmployee(Employee a)
   {
       this.list.Add(a);
   }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int Index)
    {
        var e = list[Index]; 
        return e;  //No cast needed 
    }

}
```

In this case you know have a list which supports type safety (ie you know everything in it is a Employee ) and will actually out perform the array list.

Comment: +1 for discussing the benefits of the generic List rather than just suggesting its use.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int Index)
{
  var e = list[Index];  // should work, e will be of type Object
  return (Employee) e; // <<<<<The problems
}
```

And consider using `List<Employee>` to have a more 'type-safe' collection.

```
class EmployeeList
{
    //ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast the object to the `Employee` object. Use List if you have the option.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the object as an `Employee`
Change this

```
var e = list[Index]; <<<<<The problems
```

To this

```
var e = (Employee)list[Index]; <<<<<The problems
```

like a couple of guys said, you should definitely NOT use a generic Collection/List/IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here suggest or imply that you should use

```
List<Employee>
```

rather than ArrayList in your EmployeeList class.  From your sample, it seems that EmployeeList is just a strongly-typed wrapper around ArrayList.  If that's the case, you can get rid of EmployeeList entirely and use

```
List<Employee>
```

instead.

Comment: Got the same problem again, can't understand it know
public int count()
        {
            int p = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            var e = new Employee();
            while(p == 0)
            {
                e = list[counter];
            }

        }

Comment: @MårtenCederholm what is the problem?  The code fragment in your comment is an infinite loop that does essentially nothing.  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry,
List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();

Comment: @MårtenCederholm And what's the problem with that statement?  Perhaps you should edit your question to post the current state of your code and describe the current problem.  Or perhaps a new question is warranted.